# How to get only even or odd lines from an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

```
String myData [][] = {
    {"test1","test1","test1","test1"},
    {"test2","test2","test2","test2"},
    {"test3","test3","test3","test3"},
    {"test4","test4","test4","test4"},
    {"test5","test5","test5","test5"},
    {"test6","test6","test6","test6"}
};
    
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> myArray = new ArrayList<>();
    
for (int i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    ArrayList<String> tmpArray = new ArrayList<>();
    tmpArray.add(myData[i][0]);
    tmpArray.add(myData[i][1]);
    tmpArray.add(myData[i][2]);
    tmpArray.add(myData[i][3]);
    myArray.add(tmpArray);
}
```

**I need this:**

`[[test1, test1, test1, test1], [test3, test3, test3, test3], [test5, test5, test5, test5]]`

**or**

`[[test2, test2, test2, test2], [test4, test4, test4, test4], [test6, test6, test6, test6]]`

How to divide lines into even and odd?
Make an array with even lines and odd lines?

Comment: Don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

```java
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < myArray.get(i).size(); j++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            System.out.print(myArray.get(i).get(j) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Output:

```
test1 test1 test1 test1 
test3 test3 test3 test3 
test5 test5 test5 test5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<String[]> getOddLines(String[][] table) {
    List<String[]> lines = new ArrayList<>(table.length / 2);

    for (int row = 0; row < table.length; row += 2)
        lines.add(table[row]);

    return lines;
}

public static List<String[]> getEvenLines(String[][] table) {
    List<String[]> lines = new ArrayList<>(table.length / 2);

    for (int row = 1; row < table.length; row += 2)
        lines.add(table[row]);

    return lines;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make it by this code:

```java
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> x = new ArrayList<>();

for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j += 2) {
    ArrayList<String> y = new ArrayList<>();
    y.add(myData[j][0]);
    y.add(myData[j][1]);
    y.add(myData[j][2]);
    y.add(myData[j][3]);
    myArray.add(tmpArray);
}
```

Comment: Please explain how your code works, so that it can be reused more easily

Answer (score 0):

Can we use something like this :

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String myData [][] = {
                {"test1","test1","test1","test1"},
                {"test2","test2","test2","test2"},
                {"test3","test3","test3","test3"},
                {"test4","test4","test4","test4"},
                {"test5","test5","test5","test5"},
                {"test6","test6","test6","test6"}
        };

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> myArray = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < myData.length; i+=2) {
            ArrayList<String> tmpArray = new ArrayList<>();
            tmpArray.add(myData[i][0]);
            tmpArray.add(myData[i][1]);
            tmpArray.add(myData[i][2]);
            tmpArray.add(myData[i][3]);
            myArray.add(tmpArray);
        }
        myArray.forEach(strings -> {
            System.out.println(strings);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you two Lists, one containing the even arrays, one containing the odd arrays. (Assuming this pattern of alternating even and odd indices continues)

This is a great example of when the mod operator (%) can be very useful

```
  List<String[]> oddList = new ArrayList<>();
  List<String[]> evenList = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    if (i%2 == 0) {
      oddList.add(myData[i]);
    }
    else {
      evenList.add(myData[i]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: @cy6uk is this even in response to my answer? I don't use a variable called myArray.

Comment: @cy6uk ```myArray.size()``` returns 6 in YOUR code because you run this bit of code: ```myArray.add(tmpArray);``` 6 times in your for loop.

Comment: @cy6uk it's because of ```for (int i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {```. Since myData.length is 6, the loop will run 6 times. Every time the loop runs you call ```myArray.add(tmpArray);```